# Java Set Calculator: finding complement of sets

Tags: java, arrays, set, calculator, complement

Im having trouble coding the complement of a set. For example if  Set A (x)= {1, 2, 3, 4} and Set B (y)= {5, 2, 3, 8} The complement should be x-y={1,4} or y-x={5,8}. What should I change in this code to achieve this?

```
for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < y; k++) {
        if (a[i] == b[k]) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        } else {
            flag = 0;
        }
    }

    if (flag == 0) {
        c[z++] = a[i];
    }
}

System.out.print("Complement:");
System.out.print("[ ");
for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {

    System.out.print(a[i] + ",");
}
System.out.print(" ]");
```

Comment: You should indent your wode well. This time I'll do for you, but next time think about it, it's not readable like this

Comment: Give definition of : `a, b, c, i, x, y, z, flag` please

Answer (score 0):

You should print the result c[i] instead of a[i].

```
for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
  System.out.print(a[i] + ",");
}
```